# "Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern" when doing s3.listObjects()

Tags: xml, dependencies, xerces, jaxp, tomcat9

I'm facing a curious problem. I have a Java webapp that uses the AWS sdk
My Local setup is

- Latest Docker
- Container with Centos7 + tomcat9.0.13 + JDK 1.8.0_161

One of my object key name is
".Test%Test%&Name.jpg",

When I attempt a `s3.listObject()` I get

```
by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "TE" at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:194) ~[na:1.8.0_161] at com.amazonaws.util.SdkHttpUtils.urlDecode(SdkHttpUtils.java:114) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.283.jar:na]
```

However.... for the *exact* same webapp (same war) and the same setup (EC2 centos 7, jdk 1.8.161, tomcat 9.0.13) and with the same key in S3
s3.listObject() does *not* through that exception ?

This definitely something dodgy with how the JVM loads the libraries but I cannot understand how I can check what is loaded.

I'd like to compare which XML parser is loaded on my EC2 and which parser is loaded on my local Docker setup.

Full Stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "TE"
    at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:194) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.amazonaws.util.SdkHttpUtils.urlDecode(SdkHttpUtils.java:114) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.283.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.decodeIfSpecified(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:302) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.283.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.access$200(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:100) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.283.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler.doEndElement(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:699) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.283.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.AbstractHandler.endElement(AbstractHandler.java:52) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.283.jar:na]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2967) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseXmlInputStream(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:147) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.283.jar:na]
    ... 163 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error points, it is not a valid HEX character. HEX characters start with `'%'`. You need to escape it to `%25`, which is its equivalent.

Then your escaped key name would be:

```
".Test%25Test%25&Name.jpg"
```

Hope it helps!